# What causes the application of various Status Ailments?

Tags: path-of-exile

Yes, what decides the trigger chance and duration of Chill/Freeze, Shock and Ignite?

(I've heard that the duration scales off of damage and chance... well, that it's applied on every crit, but I doubt that and would like some confirmation.)

Comment: I know stun (when you or a mob temporarily can't act after being hit) duration is determined by HP, at least in PvP (which is why CI builds are uncommon, because with 1HP it's easy to get stunned).

Comment: This is all explained in the mechanics thread.  Basically the ailments are applied when the mob crits, and the difference between being chilled and frozen is, in fact, determined by your HP.  I'll have a formal answer citing the mechanics thread, in a few minutes.

Comment: @MarcoLeblanc I was more curious of how I can apply the elemental ailments. Trying to make a melee shock build, and wondering whether to focus on crit chance or attack speed, because as I've stated, I'm not sure what nodes/weapons to look out for.

Comment: @MarcoLeblanc Hello there, Mr. "a few minutes". I'm getting kinda anxious here xD

Comment: @user1337 Sorry, I am at work and am busy today. http://www.pathofexile.com/forum/view-thread/11707/page/1 is what you should be looking at, good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shock, Freeze, and Ignite are normally applied only on **critical hits**. Chill is applied on normal hits. You can also get "% chance to Shock/Freeze/Ignite on hit" through passives, skill effects, etc. or other means. This allows you to apply these ailments with non-critical hits as well.

Dealing more damage of the corresponding element (as a portion of the target's "ailment threshold", usually equal to their life) means that a more powerful instance of the ailment will be applied. An ailment is only applied if it reaches a minimum level of power. The "power" of an ailment translates to:

- the **damage multiplier** caused by Shock
- the **% slow** applied by Chill
- the **duration** of Freeze
- the **damage** dealt by Ignite

Because critical hits deal more damage and thus inflict stronger ailments, it is usually more effective to invest in critical hit chance, rather than chance to apply ailments by other means. You can also scale up the power of ailments you inflict though "% increased effect of Shock", "% increased effect of non-damaging ailments", and similar stats.

Apart from the basic elemental ailments, there are ailments like Bleed and Poison which cannot be applied innately, and require you to use special skills, gear, or passives to apply.

Stun (which is similar, but not technically considered an ailment) can be applied by regular hits. Stronger hits have a higher chance of inflicting stun. The duration is fixed regardless of the amount of damage, but can be scaled with stats like "% increased Stun duration on enemies".

You can find more details about the [ailments](https://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Ailment) on the PoE gamepedia:

- [Shock](https://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Shock)
- [Chill](https://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Chill) and [Freeze](https://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Freeze)
- [Ignite](https://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Ignite)

Comment: I'm a year and a half late to answer your question, but maybe someone else will benefit! :)

Comment: Not even a sauce link to the gamepedia page? Also, how about the relation between the non-crit based applications of elemental statuses from passive nodes and the duration of stun effects? Really, I've already visited that page quite a few times, and was kinda looking for something closer to a clarification of the content rather than... yeah, the content.

Comment: @user1337 I'm not sure what you're asking about. Stun doesn't have any relation to other status effects.

Comment: Sorry, I just seem to recall that I read a similar article somewhere. Not gamepedia though. Okay: You said that the shortest amount of time that an elemental ailment is 300ms, and that it's related to how much damage you dealth compared to actor's total life. So, what's the relationship? Also, I know stun doesnt relate to other effects. I asked about how long stun effects lasts (not in the original question though).

Comment: @user1337 see my edit. Stun is 350 ms, Ignite is 4s, and the other effects scale linearly with damage dealt.

Comment: I think I finally got that through my thick skull. Thanks